# How do I reset Nativescript RadListView LoadOnDemand after disabling it?

Tags: nativescript

How do I reset/reactivate the RadListView load on demand feature after deactivating it by calling `list.notifyLoadOnDemandFinished(true)`?

Just calling the same function with `false` doesn't seem to do the trick, neither does calling list.notifyPullToRefreshFinished(true).

Comment: `notifyLoadOnDemandFinished(true)` actually sets `loadOnDemandMode` to `None`. So to reset, apply desired mode on `loadOnDemandMode` attribute.

Comment: Hmm nope, doesn't do it here. I output the value before and after and it's the same, and setting.

Comment: Okay, so you gave me an idea. I set the mode to `None` manually and then back to `Auto` - and that actually fixed it. That took way too long! Thanks

Comment: Hmm, that's what I'm used to and seen others widely use. `notifyLoadOnDemandFinished(true)` is not documented but just there in the TS declarations.

Answer (score 2):

You may directly operate on `loadOnDemandMode` attribute to enable / disable load on demand.

Setting `loadOnDemandMode` to `None` will disable it, setting it back to `Auto` will start triggering load on demand event again.